# Pass image from sql to C# then to JSON service

Tags: c#, javascript, json

I have a sql image field that I add to a dataTable. I then pass this image to a Json call. In the json call when trying to get the image I get the following
`image_returnset[0].Picture` holds the value of `System.Byte[]`.

How do I iterate the `System.Byte[]` and bind the image to an html image control ?

This is my C# code

```
userSqlParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
userSqlParameter.Value = itemID;

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Get_image", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add(userSqlParameter);

da.SelectCommand = cmd;

//byte[] barrImg = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Picture"];
// dt.Rows[0]["Picture"]
da.Fill(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your byte array, convert it to a Base-64 string using `Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray)`.  Store that string in your json data and return it to your browser.

```
{ myImageBase64String: "..." }
```

Once in the browser, you can assign that string to the `src` of your image like:

```
image.src = "data:image/png;" + result.myImageBase64String;
```

Comment: thanks, will this work ?
 byte[] barrImg = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Picture"];
                    dt.Rows[0]["Picture"] = Convert.ToBase64String(barrImg);

Comment: Probably not.  You may need to do some javascript on the client-side

Comment: How do I pass the base64 into a DataTable that is assigned for System.Byte[] already ?

Comment: Why do you need to put it back into the DataTable?  Just take the data and pass it using json to the client-side.

Comment: The dataTable gets serialized with DataContractJsonSerializer then it gets passed to the client side